# Easier way to generate new columns automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
sample_data={'Loan':['Loan1', 'Loan2', 'Loan3', 'Loan4'],'Balance':[1000, 500, 750, 450],
             'Driver_1':[0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.11],'Driver_2':[0.15, 0.17, 0.10, 0.09],
            'Driver_3':[0.05, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01],'Driver_4':[0.1, 0.09, 0.03, 0.02]}

df=pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
```

I want to create columns that calculate the balance after each driver (I would be happy with rows as well if the solution was better/more efficient that way).  Right now I am just doing it via "brute" force which is quite ugly and am sure inefficient.

```
df['Balance_after_D1'] = df['Balance'] * (1-df['Driver_1'])
df['Balance_after_D1_D2'] = df['Balance_after_D1'] * (1-df['Driver_2'])
df['Balance_after_D1_D2_D3'] = df['Balance_after_D1_D2'] * (1-df['Driver_3'])
df['Balance_after_D1_D2_D3_D4'] = df['Balance_after_D1_D2_D3'] * (1-df['Driver_4'])
```

My real data set has 100s of drivers and so the result would be 100s of additional columns.  It's quite simple in excel but haven't quite figured how to do it in a more automated way in Python.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a brute force way, but at least you don't need to type all of the rows on your own I guess, **I assume there is a better-optimized way to do it in pandas**.

Anyway, just replace `driver_count` with your actual driver count

```py
driver_count = 4
previous_key = 'Balance'
for driver in range(1, driver_count + 1):
   key = 'Balance_after_' + '_'.join(f'D{i}' for i in range(1, driver + 1))
   df[key] = df[previous_key] * (1 - df[f'Driver_{driver}'])
   previous_key = key
```

```
    Loan  Balance  Driver_1  Driver_2  Driver_3  Driver_4  Balance_after_D1  Balance_after_D1_D2  Balance_after_D1_D2_D3  Balance_after_D1_D2_D3_D4
0  Loan1  1000     0.10      0.15      0.05      0.10      900.0             765.000              726.75000               654.075000               
1  Loan2  500      0.20      0.17      0.01      0.09      400.0             332.000              328.68000               299.098800               
2  Loan3  750      0.15      0.10      0.07      0.03      637.5             573.750              533.58750               517.579875               
3  Loan4  450      0.11      0.09      0.01      0.02      400.5             364.455              360.81045               353.594241
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.  What if i wanted to have two values calculate against one balance?  For example if i wanted Driver_2 AND Driver_3 to calculate off of Balance_after_D1?  Sorry i forgot to specify that in my original query.